# How to receive a wifi direct file?

Tags: windows-10, android

If I want to send something via wifi direct from my android how to I enable receiving on my windows 10 laptop?

I cannot find any settings in windows to enable this.

Comment: Wifi Direct is a method of connecting, not sending files.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams this is definitely not true.

Comment: You haven't convinced me.